# Tkinter Python - Treeview

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
def add_laytime(self):
        self.variaveis()
        self.conecta_bd()

        self.cursor.execute("""
            INSERT OR IGNORE INTO laytime (vessel, comm, destino, weight, porto, loading, demurrage, 
            dispatch, allowed, day_of_oper, dem_disp, clima, estimated, r)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
            (self.vessel, self.comm, self.destino, self.weight, self.porto, self.loading, self.demurrage,
             self.dispatch, self.allowed, self.dayoper, self.demdisp, self.clima, self.estimated, self.r))

        self.conn.commit()
        self.desconecta_bd()
        self.select_lista()
        self.limpar_tela()

def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        self.limpar_tela()

        for n in self.listacli.selection():
            col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = self.listacli.item(n, 'values')
            self.vessel_entry.insert(END, col1)
            self.comm_entry.insert(END, col2)
            self.allowed_value.insert(END, col12)
            self.estimated_value.insert(END, col15)
            
    def lista_frame2(self):
        self.listacli = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_2, height=3,
                                     column=("col1", "col2", "col12", "col15"))
        self.listacli.heading("#0", text="")
        self.listacli.heading("#1", text="Vessel")
        self.listacli.heading("#2", text="Commodity")
        self.listacli.heading("#3", text="Allowed")
        self.listacli.heading("#4", text="Estimated ($)")
        
        self.listacli.column("#0", width=1)
        self.listacli.column("#1", width=50)
        self.listacli.column("#2", width=200)
        self.listacli.column("#3", width=125)
        self.listacli.column("#4", width=125)
        self.listacli.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.85)
```

I have a form that is to be filled out, and when I click to add the information and be stored in frame2, only the Ship and Commodity are saved correctly. The "allowed" is receiving the value of "dayoper" and "estimated_value" is receiving weight. In other words, the first two are right and the final two are wrong.

[image]

Comment: You have only 4 columns in the treeview (not including the *tree column*), why do you expect there are 6 values returned by `self.listacli.item(n, 'values')` inside `OnDoubleClick()`?

Comment: In fact. Even placing 4 columns, the result does not change... estimated is still getting the value from weight.

Comment: Actually it is not clear what your issue is.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: you could create `minimal working code` with example data directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it to see problem (and test modification on real code).

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: did you run code in terminal/console to see error message? In code I see variable `col12`, `col15` in `insert(END, col12)`, `insert(END, col15)` but you don't have `col12 = ...` `col15 = ...` - you have only `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = ...`. This should raise error.

Answer (score 0):

I made minimal working code to test it and I see two problems.
But both generate error message which you should see in console/terminal.

---

1. you should have only 4 variables in

```
col1, col2, col3, col4 = self.listacli.item(n, 'values')
```

Error message:

```
...
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = self.listacli.item(n, 'values')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 4)
```

---

2. you use variables `col12` and `col15` but you need `col3` and `col4`

```
self.allowed_value.insert(END, col3)    # col12
self.estimated_value.insert(END, col4)  # col15
```

Error message:

```
...
self.allowed_value.insert(END, col12)
NameError: name 'col12' is not defined
```

---

[image]

---

Full working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # ---
        
        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="Vessel:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.vessel_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.vessel_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="Comm:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.comm_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.comm_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="Allowed:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.allowed_value = tk.Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.allowed_value.grid(row=2, column=1)
        
        tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="Estimated:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.estimated_value = tk.Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.estimated_value.grid(row=3, column=1)

        # ---
        
        self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        
        self.lista_frame2()

        # --- fake data for test ---

        for x in range(1, 6):
            self.listacli.insert("", "end", text=f'{x}', values=(f'V{x}', f'C{x}', f'A{x}', f'E{x}') )
        
            
    def lista_frame2(self):
        self.listacli = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_2, height=3,
                                     column=("col1", "col2", "col12", "col15"))
        self.listacli.heading("#0", text="")
        self.listacli.heading("#1", text="Vessel")
        self.listacli.heading("#2", text="Commodity")
        self.listacli.heading("#3", text="Allowed")
        self.listacli.heading("#4", text="Estimated ($)")
        
        self.listacli.column("#0", width=1)
        self.listacli.column("#1", width=50)
        self.listacli.column("#2", width=200)
        self.listacli.column("#3", width=125)
        self.listacli.column("#4", width=125)
        #self.listacli.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.85)
        self.listacli.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        self.listacli.bind('<Double-1>', self.on_double_click)
        
    def on_double_click(self, event):   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions

        for n in self.listacli.selection():
            #col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 = self.listacli.item(n, 'values')
            col1, col2, col3, col4 = self.listacli.item(n, 'values')

            self.vessel_entry.delete(0, "end")
            self.vessel_entry.insert("end", col1)

            self.comm_entry.delete(0, "end")
            self.comm_entry.insert("end", col2)

            self.allowed_value.delete(0, "end")
            self.allowed_value.insert("end", col3)    # col12

            self.estimated_value.delete(0, "end")
            self.estimated_value.insert("end", col4)  # col15
            
        
w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```